# My Site has slowed down because of usage of Simple_html_dom in php

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I use simple_html_dom for my social bookmarking site like reddit where 15 links are displayed per page. Every time I load the page, it takes a lot of time . For ex i use similar code like below for extracting data from news websites.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.nytimes.com');
$img= $html->find('img',6);
echo'<img src="'.$img->src.'"style="height:100px;width:100px;float:left;margin-right:5px"/>';
$title = array_shift($html->find('title'))->innertext;
echo '<p style="font-size:13px"><strong>'.$title.'</strong></p>';
foreach($html->find('div') as $element)
 if($element->class=='article_txt'){
   echo $element->find('p',0);
   }
```

Is it because I use this code, which makes my site to take too much time to extract data and display? If yes, then how do I reduce the time of data extraction and display?

Comment: @Dagon can you be more specific

Comment: http://developer.nytimes.com/docs if its not available via onre of the api's then you are just stealing

Comment: just because something is on someone else's website does not give you the **right** to use it on your website, or any any other way

Comment: got it.. will take care of it..

Answer (score 2):

Every new request results in the file_get_html function fetching remote data, and, obviously, you have to wait for it to finish. You should cache those results using something like memcached http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php). After setting up memcached and Memcache, you could do something like this:

```
// You'd have to set it up before usage
$cache = new Memcache();
$key = md5('the-url-goes-here');

if (!($html = $cache->get($key)))
{
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.nytimes.com');
    $cache->set($key, $html);
}

// other code that uses $html
```

Comment: I did not understand you completely

Comment: I have shared hosting on my site, so i cannot use memcache.. can you suggest me some other way?

Comment: If you can't convince them do enable memcache, you can roll your own cache system using text files. You can either save each request in a text file or you can cache the entire page until a new link is added. You'd do it by simply saving the HTML output in a file. Check this: https://gist.github.com/4363114